# A coded conjuration from Ars Goetia

Tags: cipher

**YE FYRSTE CONJOURATIOUN**

In the name of him who spake, I invoke and move thee, King Purson exalteth
is the power of the Most High, I say unto thee, Obey! In the name of the mighty
mercene of Apologia who govern, spirits, Liachidae, and repenting above ye
ardaen the power of thee, Most High.  I say again, Obey! and it shall, in relief,
recant thy seat, joy, and power and I bind thee in the depth of Abadded.

```
KPNRFNEKUNFKYRSGKGURKOHVYQVATKGELKUVFKAVFHBPK

Uli gsv mvcg xlwv, yvdziv gsv wlfyov svc. Uli gsv urmzo xlwv, krxp gsv gdl irtsgnlhg ovggvih.  

4f 6e 63 65 20 66 6f 72 20 6e 6f 74 68 69 6e 67 2e 20 54 77 69 63 65 20 66 6f 72 20 74 68 65 20 6b 65 79 2e 20 4d 6f 76 65 20 61 6c 6f 6e 67 20 6e 6f 77 2e  

34 36 20 36 66 20 37 32 20 32 30 20 37 34 20 36 38 20 36 35 20 32 30 20 36 65 20 36 35 20 37 38 20 37 34 20 32 30 20 36 33 20 36 66 20 36 34 20 36 35 20 32 63 20 32 30 20 37 34 20 36 38 20 36 35 20 32 30 20 36 62 20 36 35 20 37 39 20 32 30 20 36 39 20 37 33 20 32 30 20 34 37 20 35 32 20 34 39 20 34 64 20 34 66 20 34 39 20 35 32 20 34 35 20 32 65 20 32 30 20 34 36 20 36 66 20 37 32 20 32 30 20 37 34 20 36 38 20 36 35 20 32 30 20 36 36 20 36 39 20 36 65 20 36 31 20 36 63 20 32 30 20 36 33 20 36 66 20 36 34 20 36 35 20 32 63 20 32 30 20 34 31 20 34 65 20 34 34 20 32 30 20 37 30 20 36 39 20 36 33 20 36 62 20 32 30 20 37 34 20 36 38 20 36 35 20 32 30 20 37 34 20 37 37 20 36 66 20 32 30 20 36 63 20 36 35 20 36 36 20 37 34 20 36 64 20 36 66 20 37 33 20 37 34 20 32 30 20 36 63 20 36 35 20 37 34 20 37 34 20 36 35 20 37 32 20 37 33 20 32 65  

LFZFVMWMTRTOCLVYYVMMQPCMTVWRHPVGUERGFIKMUETXFZCPXI...
```

**<sub>Your task is to decode the clues until the final code is revealed.

Except for the final code, all decoding can be done with [Rumkin](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/) and [Cryptii](http://cryptii.com/text/select).</sub>**
[image: KingPurson]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first line

> Entering it in to a Caesarian Shift with a shift of 13 or entering it into ROT13 directly you get: 
>  XCAESARXHASXLEFTXTHEXBUILDINGXTRYXHISXNISUOCX 
>  with the Xs being spaces, it ends up reading: 
>  "Caesar has left the building try his nisuoc"

With the hint from the first line and the second clue

> Use a substitution cipher with an inverse alphabet (A=Z, B=Y, etc.), or Atbash, deduced from "cousin" being spelt backwards in the first hint, to get: 
> "For the next code, beware the double hex. For the final code, pick the two rightmost letters."

In the third clue

> Translate from hexadecimal (but only once) to get: 
> "Once for nothing. Twice for the key. Move along now."

In the fourth clue

> Translate from hexadecimal twice to get: 
> "For the next code, the key is GRIMOIRE. For the final code, AND pick the two leftmost letters."

In the fifth clue

> Using GRIMOIRE as the key (repeating), decrypt the code using a one time pad to get: 
> "FORTHEFINALCODEUSEEACHLINEOFTHECONJURATIONLLRRLLRR..."
> Using the conjuration's lines and the first two letters and last two letters of each line as denoted in the decryptions above, I get: 
> INTHISTYMEYEAREFREED
> which I translate as a conjuration as 
> "In this tyme, ye are freed."